# What is the difference between 'making a trip' and 'taking a trip'?

Tags: meaning

Germans *make* all their trips. We *take* some trips and *make* others.
What is the difference for English speakers between "making a trip" and "taking a trip"?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=make+OR+take+a+trip

Comment: Just a tentative 'guess': "*taking* a trip" may be by choice/voluntary, e.g. holiday/vacation; "*making* a trip" may be non-voluntary, e.g. business trip. ??

Comment: @TrevorD and what's the difference between "going on a trip" and "taking a trip"? I'm asking because I don't think there is any.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't know - and you are probably correct. I'm not even sure about my comment, which is why I said it was "a tentative 'guess'". :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In American English, we use "make a trip" to refer to an errand. We ran out of milk, so I made a trip to the store. We take a trip to reach a destination for the sake of the destination, usually in terms of a vacation or recreation. "This summer, we're taking a trip to Disneyland."